# Disable IntelliJ splitting line comments on format

Tags: intellij-idea

Sometimes we have long lines of Java code. Then someone comments them out temporarily, like

```
// String asdf = "1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234_1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234";
```

Then another developer formats the whole file, which turns it into

```
    // String asdf = "1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234_1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234
    // -1234-1234-1234";
```

Then if we uncomment the code, it becomes

```
     String asdf = "1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234_1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234
     -1234-1234-1234";
```

which is a syntax error in Java.

How can we avoid this? Is there a setting to disable splitting/wrapping single-line comments? I almost universally would never want to wrap a single-line comment, even if it extends a tiny bit past the defined right margin.

Answer (score -1):

Do not wrap one line comments:

[image: do not wrap]